# Notation for a k-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading Graph Theory by Bondy and Murty. I always see the notation for a complete $k$-partite graph, but what is the notation for a $k$-partite graph? For example, my partite sets are of order $2$, $3$, and $4$, and it is not a complete $k$-partite graph. How can I write this graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just say "$3$-partite graph" or "tripartite graph", omitting the word "complete". "Bipartite graph" is certainly standard.

I assume that when you say

> my partite sets are of order $2$, $3$, and $4$

you mean a graph with $9$ vertices, $2$ red, $3$ blue and $4$ yellow, all of whose edges connect vertices of different colors.

Comment: So there is no standard notation for $k$-partite graphs, unlike the complete $k$-partite graphs which uses the notation $K_{2,3,4}$ for example?

Comment: @Brenda I know of none even for (incomplete) bipartite graphs.